# IntelliJ Spring plugin not available

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I am facing an issue with IntelliJ when trying to enable Spring support and I can't seem to figure out how to solve this.

To enable Spring I am following this guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/enabling-spring-support.html

However, there doesn't seem to be any 'Spring' plugin available to select:
[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTleC.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Which version of Intellij you're using? Spring support only available for Ultimate edition. There is no need for enabling spring support in ultimate edition, it's enabled by default.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must be using the Community Edition.  The Community Edition [does not support Spring](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

If you were using the Ultimate Edition, you'd see a screen like this when looking for Spring:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've overlooked the spring support on their website.